# How to set the starting point of x value to 0?

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I want to set the starting point of x value to 0 instead of -1 when there is one data.

This is my execution screen. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1ePA.png)

I tried many methods, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know a solution?

ArrayList values = new ArrayList<>();

```
    for (int i = 0; i < userDataList.size(); i++) {
        int time = userDataList.get(i).getTime();

        values.add(new Entry(i, time));
    }



 final ArrayList<String> xLabelList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < userDataList.size(); i++) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = simpleDateFormat.parse(Float.toString(userDataList.get(i).getDate()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
        String dateString = newFormat.format(date);

        xLabelList.add(dateString);
    }

    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
            if(value<0)
                return xLabelList.get(0);

            return xLabelList.get((int) value);

        }

    });
```

Comment: Show the best of your many attempts for us to comment on.

Comment: I used "setAxisMinimum()", "setVisibleXRange()" but it doesn't work

Comment: He means you should post some code.

Comment: Sorry, I upload my code

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true)` (it's Kotlin) so that the first and the last labels will be hidden.